# Autoit HotKeySet bug

Tags: automation, autoit

I have this code:

```
If $choixListAction == "ACTION1" Then
   HotKeySet("{ENTER}", "_getPos")
EndIf

Func _getPos()
        
    Global $posSouris = MouseGetPos()
    
    $posX = MouseGetPos(0) 
    $posY = MouseGetPos(1)
    
    Return $posX & ":" & $posY
EndFunc
```

I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> but any action work.

Comment: That's not the entire code, right? Where is $choixListAction defined?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your script isn't running anymore to process the hotkey. The following code works for me:

```
HotKeySet("{ENTER}", "_MyFunc")
While True
    Sleep(150)
WEnd

Func _MyFunc()
    MsgBox(0, "MyFunc", "Hello :)")
EndFunc   ;==>_MyFunc
```